# trying to create a dict for verifying an alien dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to solve a problem where my program would return true or false depending on whether a list of words is in order according to a custom or an "alien" dictionary.
suppose this is the order given:
 order = "hlabcdefgijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"

I tried to create a dict where the ascii value of the letter would be the key and the values would be from 0 to (len(order) - 1)
however I keep on getting the following error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
def isAlienSorted(self, words, order):

    values = []
    for i in range(0,len(order)):
        values.append(i)


    orderDict = dict(zip(order,values))
    orderDict[None] = 0

    for i in range(0,len(words) - 2):
        if len(words[i])>len(words[i+1]):
            return False
    for i in range(0,len(words) - 2):
        for j in words[i]:
            if orderDict[words[i][j]]>orderDict[words[i+1][j]]:
                return False

    return True
```

only 1 test case has passed:

1 / 115 test cases passed.

Why am I getting this runtime error?

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The error gets thrown at the following line:

```
(Line 21) if orderDict[words[i][j]]>orderDict[words[i+1][j]]:
```

Comment: Input: words = ["hello","leetcode"], order = "hlabcdefgijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Output: true
Explanation: As 'h' comes before 'l' in this language, then the sequence is sorted.

Input: words = ["word","world","row"], order = "worldabcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz"
Output: false
Explanation: As 'd' comes after 'l' in this language, then words[0] > words[1], hence the sequence is unsorted.

Comment: Input: words = ["apple","app"], order = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Output: false
Explanation: The first three characters "app" match, and the second string is shorter (in size.) According to lexicographical rules "apple" > "app", because 'l' > '∅', where '∅' is defined as the blank character which is less than any other character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `words = ['apple', 'app']` and `i` is an `int` then `words[i]` will be a element of the list. if `i = 0` then `words[i] == 'apple'`. Now, when you say

```py
for j in words[i]:
```

`j` will be `['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']`.
`words[i][j]` wold be something like: `words[0]['a']`: `'apple'['a']` which is a `TypeError`

What you want is just `j` not `words[i][j]`